# How do I handle deletes in Vue Apollo with deeply nested queries?

Tags: vue.js, graphql, apollo-client

I have a query that returns multiple nested objects to render a screen full of information. I want to delete one of the deeply-nested objects and update the screen optimistically (i.e. without running the complete query).

To explain the query and UI, I'll use a Trello board -like query as an example:

```
query everything {
  getBoard(id: "foo") {
    name
    cardLists {        
      edges {
        node {
          id
          name
          cards {
            edges {
              node {
                id
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result of this query is used to build a UI like this: https://d3uepj124s5rcx.cloudfront.net/items/170a0V1j0u0S2p1l290I/Board.png

I'm building the app using:

- VueJS
- Vue Apollo
- Scaphold.io as my GraphQL store

When I want to delete one of the cards, I call:

```
deleteCard: function () {
  this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: gql`
      mutation deleteCard($card: DeleteCardInput!) {
        deleteCard(input: $card) {
          changedCard {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    `,
    variables: {
      'card': {
        id: this.id
      }
    },
  })
  .then(data => {
    // Success
  })
}
```

The mutation is successfully deleting the card, but I want to update the UI immediately based on the mutation. The simple option for doing this is to call `refetchQueries: ['everything']` — but this is an expensive query and too slow for quick UI updates.

What I want to do is update the UI optimistically, but the [example mutations](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo#mutations) for Vue Apollo don't address either deletes or the deeply-nested scenario.

What is the right solution / best-practices for deleting an item from a deeply-nested query, and optimistically updating the UI?

Comment: How do you update the query after the mutation, using `updateQueries` or the `dataIdFromObject` property of the apollo client?

Comment: @Locco0_0 – I'm using `updateQueries`. Is it possible for me to use `dataIdFromObject` to delete that object from the store directly, rather than updating the query?

Comment: Yes if you add a deeper nesting to the return value of the mutation, e.g. add the id of the cardLists and therein the cards. But its of course slower.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for the [optimistic Response](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/mutations.html#optimistic-ui) of apollo you see that the optimistic response "fakes" the mutation result.

So it will handle the `updateQueries` function with the optimistic values. In your case this means that if you add the `optimisticResponse` property it should alter the query inside the apollo store with the optimistic values:

Could look like this:

```js
this.$apollo.mutate({
  mutation: gql `
      mutation deleteCard($card: DeleteCardInput!) {
        deleteCard(input: $card) {
          changedCard {
            id
          }
        }
      }
    `,
  variables: {
    'card': {
      id: this.id
    }
  },
  updateQueries: {
    // .... update Board
  },
  optimisticResponse: {
    __typename: 'Mutation',
    deleteCard: {
      __typename: 'Card', // graphQL type of the card
      id: this.id,
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Thanks. The bit I'm unclear about though is how to write `updateQueries` so that I can very efficiently remove the appropriate node from the existing query, rather than re-querying the entire board again, which is slow.

Comment: I see. Then you might want to look for [reacts immutability helper](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html). Then you have to search for the correct element inside your deep nested query. Looks tough

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I'll check it out. I'm using Vue, but reading up on React's immutability helper might help inform me.

Comment: In the meantime I've realised I can easily load the parent list (and it's child cards) in the mutation query, to have Apollo automatically update the UI. It's still a too-expensive query, but better than reloading the whole board.

Comment: Yeah i guess its too expensive to load so much of the tree. But as you said better than refetching the whole board.